# Can the content of a CSS Pseudo element made visible to copy/paste?

Tags: html, css

I'm accessing a page with stylesheet containing an entry like this:

```css
.label::after {
  content: ':';
}
```

As expected, elements styled with class 'label' appear in the browser with a colon following them.  However, when I use the mouse to select a region containing this, the colon is not highlighted with the rest of the text.  More importantly, the colon is not copied to the clipboard.

Is there any way to use CSS for a browser to include the colon character when copying to the clipboard?